# GRPC Python - What is the correct way to handle socket error?

Tags: sockets, grpc-python

The error :

```
Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with: status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE details = "Socket closed" debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1576780304.349820911","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:104.155.6.79:443","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1046,"grpc_message":"Socket closed","grpc_status":14}
```

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps-booking/reference/grpc-api-v2/status_codes) for this error is saying : `The service is currently unavailable. This is most likely a transient condition, which can be corrected by retrying with a backoff.`

I found that the backoff [GRPC ARGS available](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/core/group__grpc__arg__keys.html) are :

```
grpc.initial_reconnect_backoff_ms
grpc.max_reconnect_backoff_ms
grpc.min_reconnect_backoff_ms
```

These args seems to [have these values by default](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/subchannel.cc#L62-L66)

```
#define GRPC_SUBCHANNEL_INITIAL_CONNECT_BACKOFF_SECONDS 1
#define GRPC_SUBCHANNEL_RECONNECT_MIN_TIMEOUT_SECONDS 20
#define GRPC_SUBCHANNEL_RECONNECT_MAX_BACKOFF_SECONDS 120
```

How do you know how many times the backoff will retry ? Is it linked to "grpc.enable_retries"? because the doc mentions "[transparent retries](https://github.com/grpc/proposal/blob/master/A6-client-retries.md#transparent-retries)" and I am not sure it is linked to backoff options.

**What is the correct way to handle code 14 error?**

Comment: Hello, I have the exact same issue - did you ever find out how to properly handle retries using grpc/pythion client library ?